# Blank product Image on category page Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, product-images, category-products, image-preview

When i upload  images  from admin for a product of low size it give blank  product image on **category page** but when i upload image of large size,then it shows properly , [image]

Comment: Hello, maybe your images are corrupted? Does they open and are visible if you upload them to the wysiwyg editor firstly :)

Comment: images are not corrupted , because on each  product detail page these  images show properly,

Comment: Have you tried playing around with etc/view.xml file in your theme? 
I would try to check how product images are being fetched to see whether it is a not returned from backend or there is an issue in your theme files.
Also if this issue is happening with default magento installation, please consider reporting this issue.

Comment: yes , i have played alot with view.xml but issue not resolve ,
yes ,i checked by selecting luma  theme too,it also same issue occur,
i checked in magento 2.3.4 fresh installation this issue not occuring,

Comment: Then sorry, but this is as far as I can help :) I would try to debug code how images are fetched, there is nothing more I can do. Good luck.

Comment: No problem...Thanks for your help........!!